# Django Template If Eq

Tags: django

Im trying to write within my django template a piece that will display text if it is a certain user.

i.e

```
{{ user }}
{% if user == "bob.smith" %}
    <p>Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

However Hello never prints even though the output to `{{ user }}` is shown as bob.smith.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you show your view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django represents user with its **unicode** method which connects first und last name like `(%s.%s) % (first_name, last_name)`.

If you really want to hardcode in HTML like you showed then you better go for the users primary key / id like (just replace the 1 with bob.smith primary key or id):

```
{% if user.pk == 1 %}
    <p>Hello</p>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.